# Redefining a value for each statement?

Tags: javascript, html, css, math, formula

In the project that I'm working on I want for different elements to fade in and out as you scroll along. 
I defined the opacity of the element as `f(x)=a ( x - d ) ^ 2 + e` where the opacity would be `f(x)` and `x` would be `$(window).scrollTop ()`. `e` would be `>=1`.
The elements should fade in and out after each other with slight overlap, so for each element the parabola would have to move further along the x axis.

```
var alpha = -0.000009 * ((Math.pow($(window).scrollTop () + delta),  2)) + 1;
$('#content').css({'opacity':alpha});
```

That would be part of a function triggered by scrolling.
This works for element #1 but for the following elements I'd have to change delta. Is there a way to define it's value differently for each element? Or would I have to manually change it for each one? I was hoping to keep this as simple as possible.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle out of it https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: `#content` is an id reference, elements should have unique id's. Do all the elements you want to apply this behaviour share a class, for instance?

Comment: Kind of sollution : give delta to content element as a data-param and while init make something like :
$('.elements').each(function(){  $(this).css({'opacity': -0.000009 * ((Math.pow($(window).scrollTop () + parseInt( $(this).data('delta') ),  2)) + 1; });   } )

Comment: @Jamie That's just an example. I would rewrite that last part for each element so they can each call on the formula with a different value for delta, that is if this is even possible.

Comment: I also tried @xAqweRx solution and it seems to call the data-param of the first element but not the following, so all elements appear and disappear at once.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to define it's value differently for each element?

Yes, you could use an attribute `data-delta` on each element, and read that as part of your function

```
<div id="content" data-delta="1.23">Content here</div>
```

read it with `.data("delta")` given an element reference

```
var $elem = $('#content');
var delta = $elem.data("delta");
var alpha = -0.000009 * ((Math.pow($(window).scrollTop () + delta),  2)) + 1;
$elem.css({'opacity':alpha});
```

Comment: I tried this and while it works I'd have to repeat this line of code again and again, and if I do that I might as well change delta for each element's formula.

Comment: @KiraNouveau - only because you are using id. As you commented `That's just an example. I would rewrite that last part for each element so they can each call on the formula with a different value for delta` - i thought you realised you should be doing this in some sort of loop, reading the `delta` from each element in the loop.